# Trouble making overflow working with rails iteration

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on developing a messaging system in my rails app. Right now what I'm doing is rendering all of the current_user's conversations&messages on one view, hiding them when the page loads, and displaying the messages associated with the user who the current_user selects(from a list of users whom the current_user has already started conversations). The problem I've run in to is that as the number of messages increase, so does the length of the page. To help this, I wrapped all of the messages that will be rendered in a div, and gave said div an overflow property of hidden(originally I set it to auto, but switched to hidden to see if prop would work at all). This has not worked, unfortunately.

The view (the list from which the user will select who to message is in the layout)

```
<div id="message-view" class="">
<% @conversations.each do |convo| %>
  <div id="<%= convo.id %>" class="tabcontent conversations-message">
    <% convo.messages.each do |message| %>
      <% if message.user != current_user %>
        <div class="float-left small">
          <%= message.body %>
        </div><br>
      <% else %>
        <div class="float-right small">
          <%= message.body %>
        </div><br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
  <div class="message-bar">
      message bar
  </div>
</div>
```

The css

```
#message-view{
  position: relative;
}
#message-view .message-bar{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(232,233,232);
  width: 73%;
}
.search-conversations{
  height: 30px; width: 210px;
}
.grey{
  background-color: rgb(236,236,236);
}
.conversations-message{
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Problem

[image: Messages continue on despite the overflow property]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a rails question, but rather html/css.

Try setting your div's `display` to `none` rather than hiding it any other way. This way other, longer conversations will not make the conversation box larger than necessary.
Regarding sizing the whole thing as designed, check out flex and/or css-grid, which allow you to do this. A short example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ce06r98v/

Great resource to learn flexbox: https://flexboxfroggy.com/
Or if you want to go with grid: http://cssgridgarden.com/